# Llenar datos de un select

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando cargar los respectivos datos de un articulo por medio de su id, desde el formulario de registro, donde esta información solo sera visible no podrá modificar. Ya he intentado varias maneras pero no logro conseguir mi objetivo, alguien que me pueda ayudar.

`onchange` del combobox

```
<div class="col-md-9 ml-auto">
     <label>Item Description</label>
     <select onchange="displayInformation(this.value)" class="form-control" id="descriptionItem"></select>
     <br>
</div>


//function
function displayInformation(numFile){    
    console.log(numFile);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/receipt.php?numFile='+ numFile,
        type: "GET",
        success:function(data)
        {
        FullDates();
        }
    });
}
```

Aquí es donde estoy intentando asignar la información a cada input

```
function FullDates(image,cat_name,idSub,numFile,name_category,name_sub,name_unit,name_location,
model_item,quantity,price_item,company_supplier,manufacturer,commentt,name_engineer)
{
console.log("Entre a FullDates");
console.log(numFile);

        document.getElementById("imagenEditar").src = "http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/" + image;
        document.getElementById("reciNumPart").value =  cat_name+"-"+idSub+"-"+numFile;
        document.getElementById("reciCategory").value = name_category;
        document.getElementById("reciSubItem").value = name_sub;
        document.getElementById("reciUnit").value = name_unit;
        document.getElementById("reciAreas").value = name_location;
        document.getElementById("reciModel").value = model_item;
        document.getElementById("AllQuantity").value = quantity;
        document.getElementById("reciPrice").value = price_item;
        document.getElementById("reciSupplier").value = company_supplier;
        document.getElementById("reciManufacturer").value = manufacturer;
        document.getElementById("reciComment").value = commentt;
        document.getElementById("ReciEngineer").value = name_engineer;    
        }
```

[image: Al seleccionar cualquier valor del select, si detecta el id,pero sus datos salen undefined]

Comment: Pregunta en tu petición de ajax en el success ¿Ya intentaste la impreción de data para ver que te responde tu servicio? Si es así tu código javascript donde asignas los valores a los elementos html ¿Se encuentra dentro del success o fuera?

Comment: Comprueba tu function FullDates, ya que recibe unos parametros, y según tu ejemplo no se lo estas pasando.

Answer (score -1):

[image]Al dar clic sobre una opcion del select, del cual quiero que se cargue su informacion,si esta cachando su id,y entra a fullDates el cual pondra su informacion en los input...ese es el resultado del data, si me devuelve su informacion, sin embargo siguen saliend indefinidos en el formulario

[image]Aqui esta mi funcion donde mando a llamar mi api, y despues la funcion que asignara la informacion a los input, sinceramente no se si es la manera correcta, ya estoy confundida con tantas cosas que he intentado